# Entire page appearing twice in the DOM in LEX?

Tags: lightning, html, dom

So the two snippets in this screenshot are *the same page* loaded in Lightning. This is the "main div" as I can see it that holds the main contents of the page. I promise it is the same page, a standard Account page layout, snapped twice, so *why is it so different?*

[image: Comparison Screen shots]

The top snip is when I view the source of the page from a fresh load (F5) of the record detail page.  There is one `div` "center oneCenterStage" (number 1) and this holds all the DOM for the whole detail page section, very neat. The second snip is what gets loaded into the browser when I navigate to the (same) Account page from a link *within* LEX... say from a List View.

*NOW* In that second snip, the *entire DOM of my page* exists within `div 1` (windowViewMode-Normal) *and* `div 3` (oneCenterStage) (but `div 2` (windowViewMode-minimized) is basically empty). This means some work I have on the page which is dependent on targetting a bit of the account page gets knackered - because the entire page exists twice in the DOM (Style IDs and all).

It looks fine in the browser because, in snip two, `div 3` (where the content actually was in the first case) is set to `display: none` so it doesn't display, but it *still does mess up the DOM* because it's *still there*.

Why on earth is this? More importantly, how can I stop Salesforce putting the whole page in twice? It can't be good for performance either.

Comment: Maybe they did it just for lafs?